# Matplotlib axis is shrinking over iteration

Tags: axis, colorbar, matplotlib-3d

I'm trying to perform iterative 3D plots on a given axis. This process will be entailed in a Tkinter application, so I can't simply destroy/create a new figure, I must refresh the axis and colorbar.

Here is a simple example : the idea is to create a 3D axis, scatter 3D data and add a colorbar. At every iteration I remove the data and the colorbar if existing.

First iteration is perfect. But over iteration, the space given for the axis is reducing. It looks like the axis and the colorbar are placed within the space of axis build at the previous iteration.

I've tried tight_layout, removing previous data, removing colorbars. Doesn't seem to be the right way to do it
How can I proceed to always keep the full display of the first iteration ?

```
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import matplotlib
    matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
    
    x = range(10)
    y = range(10)
    z = range(10)
    data = np.random.randn(10, 5)
    
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')
    plt.show(block=False)
    for i in range(data.shape[-1]):
        if 'colorbar' in fig.get_children()[-1]._label:  # If children is colorbar
            fig.get_children()[-1].remove()  # Remove colorbar
            scat.remove()
            fig.tight_layout()
    
        scat = ax.scatter3D(x, y, z, c=data[:, i], cmap='hot')
        cb = fig.colorbar(scat)
```

[Iteration 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wiI64.png)
[Iteration 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FpIP4.png)

Answer (score 0):

Solved !

I tricked a bit using an secondary axis for the colorbar :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")

x = range(10)
y = range(10)
z = range(10)
data = np.random.randn(10, 5)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')
plt.show(block=False)
for i in range(data.shape[-1]):
    try:
        scat.remove()
        cb.remove()
    except:
        pass

    ax.set_position([0,0,0.8,1])
    ax_cb = fig.add_axes([0.8,0.1,0.1,0.8])
    scat = ax.scatter3D(x, y, z, c=data[:, i], cmap='hot')
    cb = fig.colorbar(scat, cax=ax_cb)
```